# AppScript is not sending Emails automatically

Tags: google-apps-script

Using below AppScript to sending an auto email based on Google Sheet values but its not working.

I have changed the Column reference according to the current columns but its not giving an error but also not sending the email.

can someone please look into this matter.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    function Send_email() { 

  var INITIALline = 2; 
  var columnSEND = 5;  
  var STATUScolumn = 16;
  var textCONDITION = "New Request";
  var textSENT = "Mail_Sent"
    
  var tab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data"); 
  var interval = tab.getRange(INITIALline,1,tab.getLastRow()-INITIALline+1,STATUScolumn);
  var dice = interval.getValues();
  var yousent = false;
  var email,subject,message;
  
  for (var i=0; i<dice.length; ++i) {
    if((dice[i][columnSEND-1]==textCONDITION) && (dice[i][STATUScolumn-1]!=textSENT)){
    
      var email    = dice[i][9]
    
      subject = dice[i][6]+" | YOUR CASE ID IS | "+dice[i][0];
            
      var message = "<font size='3' face='Comfortaa'>Dear "+dice[i][6]+",<br/><br/>"+
      
                     "Thanks for connecting with us."+dice[i][0]+".<br/><br/>"+
                     
                     "<i>Thanks & Regards</i><br/>"+
                     "<b>VNA SERVICE TEAM </b>";
      
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message,{ htmlBody: message});
      tab.getRange(INITIALline+i,STATUScolumn).setValue(textSENT);
      yousent = true;
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Spreadsheet, it seems that `Your issue` is the column "E". But `columnSEND` is `15` by `var columnSEND = 15` of your script in your question. In this case, the if statement of `if((dice[i][columnSEND-1]==textCONDITION) && (dice[i][STATUScolumn-1]!=textSENT)){` checks the column "O". I think that this is the reason of your issue.

So in order to check the column "E", as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var columnSEND = 15;
```

#### To:

```
var columnSEND = 5;
```

Comment: Tanaike, after setting it to 5 this error is appear <> Exception: Invalid email: ABC (line 29, file "Code") and Col"O" is nothing i do not want to involve Col"O in code, it might will be last Col"P" where that text will automatically set after sent the email "Mail_Sent"

Comment: Edit the code Column according to the sheet but Email is not send

Comment: @Learning Thank you for replying. From your replying, it is found that the script in the if statement is run. About the error message of `Invalid email: ABC`, it seems that your current script retrieves the email from the column "O". But in your script in your question, the email address is retrieved from the column "J". So I'm worry about your current script and/or your Spreadsheet are different from your published information. So can you confirm your current script and your sample Spreadsheet again?

Comment: Thank you Sir for helping, My current Sheet that is attached is different from script, This sheet has different Columns which i am trying to set in script. I would request that please help in this regrad.

Comment: @Learning Thank you for replying. From your updated script, it seems that you want to put `Mail_Sent` the column "O". Is this correct?

Comment: Tanaike, Mail_Sent will be in col"P" i have updated it to Col"P" 16 but its not working on auto

Comment: @Learning Thank you for replying. I'm confusing for your current situation now. In your question, your provided sample Spreadsheet and your script are different from your current script and Spreadsheet? I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to share the same information with you, can you provide your current script and sample Spreadsheet? Because when your current script and Spreadsheet are different from your published them, it is difficult to find the reason of your current issue. How about this?

Comment: Sir, i really do apologize that i could not elaborate my problem well. I only have this code which i was using in different sheet. Now i have created this new sheet where i applied previous sheet code to make it work for this sheet. I just want this code to work in this sheet that i have attached above.

Comment: @Learning Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to share the same information with you, where can I see your current script and sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: Sir thank you its start working but its still not automate. I have to run code each time to send email i want to set the trigger in Col"E"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood the issue was resolved. About `but its still not automate`, can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Learning You want to automatically run when the column "E" is edited. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226187/discussion-between-learning-and-tanaike).